# parity cors null throws error

Tags: parity

I just reinstalled parity and I'm getting an error now. 
In my `config.toml` file when I add

```
cors = "null"
```

I get following error

```
Loading config file from /root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/config.toml
You might have supplied invalid parameters in config file.
invalid type: string "null", expected a sequence for key `rpc.cors`
```

the weird thing is it worked previously and now it doesn't

Comment: What version of parity do you use ?

Comment: version Parity/v1.9.0-unstable-51e6e0b4b-20171230/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.22.1

Comment: You should try a stable version. I recommend 1.7.11 . The property `cors = "null"` is working fine on my node.

Comment: how do I install a stable version when building from source?

Comment: Pull the tag v1.7.11 rather than the master branch. `git checkout tags/v1.7.11`

Comment: this gives me this version: version Parity/v1.7.11-unstable-a5ed4cfc4-20171228/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.22.1
its unstable as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to include following option when launching parity.

```
--jsonrpc-cors null
```